# Rodeo UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, utf-8

I have just started using Python3. I am trying to open a csv file using Rodeo IDE

```
fp = open('Proteomics_Data.csv') # open file on read mode
lines = fp.read().split("\n") # create a list containing all lines
```

I am getting an error I paste it below.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-347-aebf19dd596a> in <module>()
----> 1 lines = fp.read().split("\n")
/Users/alessandro/anaconda/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What I have found so far is the terminal not being set to UTF-8, but apparently Python 3 does not need UTF-8. I am not sure tif this could be a problem related to the IDE?

Comment: try specifying the encoding in the `open`

Comment: there are different encoding like utf-8 utf-16 etc. so try specifying any one of them and see if it works

Comment: @AI14 posted an answer for future refs and readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding in the `open` function call.

```
fp = open('Proteomics_Data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

When I save a file as `CSV` I actually get two options:

`CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)(.csv)` and `Comma Separated Values(.csv)`

If I save with the second option (Comma Separated Values) I don't need to add `encoding='utf-8'`