# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, encoding, windows-10, anaconda, smtplib

I try to send email thanks to a python script and it's not working. I tried different mail adresses (Hotmail and Gmail), different ports, etc. none is working and I always have the same adress even if I just write two lines of code. I also try Latin-1 or utf-8 encoding...nothing change!

I am working with anaconda and python 3.6 on windows10.

Code :

```
import smtplib
serveur = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

And the error :

```
runfile('C:/Users/Come/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts/sanstitre3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Come/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-a733f02e7871>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Come/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts/sanstitre3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Come/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts')

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile 
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile 
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Come/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Network Shortcuts/sanstitre3.py", line 9, in <module>
serveur = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\smtplib.py", line 261, in __init__
fqdn = socket.getfqdn()

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

EDIT :

So far I tried differnt things but Nothing worked :

no my code begin like :

```
# -*- coding:Latin-1 -*-
import smtplib
import socket
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = socket.gethostbyaddr('smtp.gmail.com')
socket.getfqdn()
socket.gethostname()
serveur = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
serveur.ehlo()
```

I also ping smtp.gmail.com, here is the result, all seem in order... but it's still not working (I also checked if any specific characters weren't in my files names)

```
Envoi d’une requête 'ping' sur gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [74.125.206.108] avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 74.125.206.108 : octets=32 temps=8 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 74.125.206.108 : octets=32 temps=7 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 74.125.206.108 : octets=32 temps=7 ms TTL=47
Réponse de 74.125.206.108 : octets=32 temps=6 ms TTL=47

Statistiques Ping pour 74.125.206.108:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 6ms, Maximum = 8ms, Moyenne = 7ms
```

Finally I don't think the error comes from the message because so far it's just "my message"...

EDIT 2 :

I may have found the problem but I don't know how to solve it!

if I write directly those lines :

```
In[59]: import socket

In[60]: socket.gethostname()
Out[60]: 'Côme'
```

I can see there is a problem with the hostname... but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rodeo UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487013/rodeo-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-0-or)

Comment: ok, I already specified the encoding at the beginning of the script and I have no $open$ or so... should I specify the encoding somewhere else?

Comment: I don' see any... I create a test file on my desktop

Comment: Do you get the same error for `socket.gethostbyaddr('smtp.gmail.com')`? Do you get it for other hosts, too?

Answer (score 1):

so the problem wasn't the script but the name... of the computer itself!

if you face the same problem change your computer's name and it should work!

Thanks for your help....

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
serveur = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

Comment: Hi,I just tried, I have the same answer/error...

I am wondering if the problem is not coming from the encoding because even if I set up the Latin-1 encoding it seems the script keep using ut-8 encoding... is that possible?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried

`serveur = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com'.encode('utf8'),587)`

Comment: It's not working either... at the bottom on my file it's still writing : "entcoding:ASCII"...